# Merge dataframes based on regex condition

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

This problem involves R. I have two dataframes, represented by this minimal reproducible example:

```
a <- data.frame(geocode_selector = c("36005", "36047", "36061", "36081", "36085"), county_name = c("Bronx", "Kings", "New York", "Queens", "Richmond"))
b <- data.frame(geocode = c("360050002001002", "360850323001019"), jobs = c("4", "204"))
```

An example to help communicate the very specific operation I am trying to perform: the `geocode_selector` column in dataframe `a` contains the FIPS county codes of the five boroughs of NY. The `geocode` column in dataframe `b` is the 15-digit ID of a specific Census block. The first five digits of a `geocode` match a more general `geocode_selector`, indicating which county the Census block is located in. I want to add a column to `b` specifying which county each census block falls under, based on which `geocode_selector` each `geocode` in `b` matches with.

Generally, I'm trying to merge dataframes based on a regex condition. Ideally, I'd like to perform a full merge carrying all of the columns of `a` over to `b` and not just the `county_name`.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
b[, "county_name"] <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {.
    if (grepl(data.a$geocode_selector[j], b$geocode[i]) == TRUE) {
      b$county_name[i] <- a$county_name[j]
    }
  }
}
```

but it took an extremely long time for the large datasets I am actually processing and the finished product was not what I wanted.

Any insight on how to merge dataframes conditionally based on a regex condition would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if (… == TRUE)` is meaningless code: just write `if (…)`, no need to *ever* write `== TRUE`: that’s literally what `if` already does.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this...

```
b$geocode_selector <- substr(b$geocode,1,5)
b2 <- merge(b, a, all.x=TRUE) #by default it will merge on common column names

b2
  geocode_selector         geocode jobs county_name
1            36005 360050002001002    4       Bronx
2            36085 360850323001019  204    Richmond
```

If you wish, you can delete the `geocode_selector` column from `b2` with `b2[,1] <- NULL`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to create the 'geocode_selector' and then do the join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[as.data.table(b)[, geocode_selector := sub('^(.{5}).*', '\\1', geocode)], 
                     on = .(geocode_selector)]
#   geocode_selector county_name         geocode jobs
#1:            36005       Bronx 360050002001002    4
#2:            36085    Richmond 360850323001019  204
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to use dplyr. I also tend to like the string handling functions in stringr, such as `str_sub`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

a <- data_frame(geocode_selector = c("36005", "36047", "36061", "36081", "36085"), 
                county_name = c("Bronx", "Kings", "New York", "Queens", "Richmond"))
b <- data_frame(geocode = c("360050002001002", "360850323001019"), 
                jobs = c("4", "204"))

b %>%
  mutate(geocode_selector = str_sub(geocode, end = 5)) %>%
  inner_join(a, by = "geocode_selector")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>           geocode  jobs geocode_selector county_name
#>             <chr> <chr>            <chr>       <chr>
#> 1 360050002001002     4            36005       Bronx
#> 2 360850323001019   204            36085    Richmond
```